# rails how to add in :include for a multiple index key association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, include, indexing

I have started off by following this guide here [Rails - Multiple Index Key Association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421873/rails-multiple-index-key-association)

I have tried to add in :include to speed up the association but im getitng this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in ItemsController#show

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: links.item_id: SELECT "links".* FROM "links" WHERE ("links".item_id = 19)
```

here's what i have:

item.rb

```
 class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :links, :dependent => :destroy, :uniq => true
    belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :user

    is_sluggable :name

     def links
      Link.by_item(self)
     end
```

link.rb

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item1, :class_name => 'Item', :foreign_key => :item1_id
  belongs_to :item2, :class_name => 'Item', :foreign_key => :item2_id
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :item1_id
  validates_presence_of :item2_id
  validates_uniqueness_of :item1_id, :scope => :item2_id, :message => "This combination already exists!"

  def self.by_item(item)
    where("item1_id = :item_id OR item2_id = :item_id", :item_id => item.id)
  end
end
```

items_controller.rb

```
  def show
    @item = Item.find_using_slug(params[:id], :include => [:category, :user, :links])
```

It works okay without :links inside :include. But otherwise I get the error.

From what I understand, the item_id is stored in the links table as item1_id or item2_id, which is why it cannot be found. Is there a workaround for this because I will be heavily referencing the links records. I am not so good with the SQL stuff.

Also unsure what's the best way to set up an Index

Willing to try out any advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the `has_many :links` association setup in `Item`. By default, this gets converted to a SQL query which looks for all links which have an `item_id` of the current `Item`. To override this default behavior, specify the find SQL yourself like this:

```
has_many :links, :dependent => :destroy, :uniq => true, :finder_sql => 'SELECT DISTINCT(*) FROM links WHERE item1_id = #{id} OR item2_id = #{id}'
```

Comment: links table has a item1_id and item2_id because it is used for a link between two items from the item table

Comment: Ah, now I see it. You are trying to pair up (link) two items together and do it only once for each pair. I'm not sure if you can wire up associations like that. The has_many :links association goes to look for all links that have an item_id value of the current Item's primary key (id). You could at least do has_one :link_1 and has_one :link_2.

Comment: Oh, I think you can define how the associations are fetched with has_many. You could define a custom SQL query in there. Let me check the docs.

Comment: Eh, well obviously since Rails doesn't eagerly fetch associations by default. Try this in your console to understand: item = Item.first and then item.links. The first statement should work and the second one break. Add the above custom find SQL and it should work.

Comment: actually both statements work.  I tried adding in your modified SQL statement, it gives me NameError in ItemsController#show

undefined local variable or method `id' for #<Class:0x007ff504a587b8>

Comment: Ah, my bad.. it should be within single-quotes. I've corrected it.

Comment: i been trying, but putting that line into item.rb doesn't seem to do any difference

Comment: yeah i think it is really impossible for me to use :includes straight with a custom finder sql in my other model. i think i might try a different route instead :(