# Rails association with multiple foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, model-associations

I want to be able to use two columns on one table to define a relationship. So using a task app as an example.

**Attempt 1:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "owner_id"
  belongs_to :assignee, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "assignee_id"
end
```

So then `Task.create(owner_id:1, assignee_id: 2)`

This allows me to perform `Task.first.owner` which returns *user one* and `Task.first.assignee` which returns *user two* but `User.first.task` returns nothing. Which is because task doesn't belong to a user, they belong to *owner* and *assignee*. So,

**Attempt 2:**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, foreign_key: [:owner_id, :assignee_id]
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

That just fails altogether as two foreign keys don't seem to be supported.

So what I want is to be able to say `User.tasks` and get both the users owned and assigned tasks.

Basically somehow build a relationship that would equal a query of `Task.where(owner_id || assignee_id == 1)`

Is that possible?

## Update

I'm not looking to use `finder_sql`, but this issue's unaccepted answer looks to be close to what I want: [Rails - Multiple Index Key Association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421873/rails-multiple-index-key-association)

So this method would look like this,

**Attempt 3:**

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.by_person(person)
    where("assignee_id => :person_id OR owner_id => :person_id", :person_id => person.id
  end 
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  def tasks
    Task.by_person(self)
  end 
end
```

Though I can get it to work in `Rails 4`, I keep getting the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid: missing value for :owner_id in :donor_id => :person_id OR assignee_id => :person_id
```

Comment: Is this gem what you're looking for? https://github.com/composite-primary-keys/composite_primary_keys

Comment: Thanks for the info mus but this is not what I'm looking for. I want a query for either or column being a given value. Not a composite primary key.

Comment: yeah, the update makes it clear. Forget about the gem. We both thought you just want to use a composed primary key. This should be possible at least by defining a custom scope a scoped relationship. Interesting scenario. I'll have a look a it later

Comment: FWIW my goal here is to get a given users task and retain the ActiveRecord::Relation format so I can continue to use task scopes on the result for search/filtering.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

## TL;DR

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def tasks
    Task.where("owner_id = ? OR assigneed_id = ?", self.id, self.id)
  end
end
```

Remove `has_many :tasks` in `User` class.

---

Using `has_many :tasks` doesn't make sense at all as we do not have any column named `user_id` in table `tasks`.

What I did to solve the issue in my case is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :owned_tasks,    class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "owner_id"
  has_many :assigned_tasks, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "assignee_id"
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner,    class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :assignee, class_name: "User"
  # Mentioning `foreign_keys` is not necessary in this class, since
  # we've already mentioned `belongs_to :owner`, and Rails will anticipate
  # foreign_keys automatically. Thanks to @jeffdill2 for mentioning this thing 
  # in the comment.
end
```

This way, you can call `User.first.assigned_tasks` as well as `User.first.owned_tasks`.

Now, you can define a method called `tasks` that returns the combination of `assigned_tasks` and `owned_tasks`.

That could be a good solution as far the readability goes, but from performance point of view, it wouldn't be that much good as now, in order to get the `tasks`, two queries will be issued instead of once, and then, the result of those two queries need to be joined as well.

So in order to get the tasks that belong to a user, we would define a custom `tasks` method in `User` class in the following way:

```
def tasks
  Task.where("owner_id = ? OR assigneed_id = ?", self.id, self.id)
end
```

This way, it will fetch all the results in one single query, and we wouldn't have to merge or combine any results.

Comment: This solution is great! It does imply a requirement for separate access to assign, owned and all tasks respectively. Something that on a large project would be great forethoguht. That however was not a requirement in my case. As for `has_many` "not making sense" If you read the accepted answer you'd see we did not end up using a `has_many` declaration at all. Assuming your requirements match the needs of every other visitor is unproductive, this answer could have been a less judgmental.

Comment: That being said I do believe this is the better long term setup we should be advocating to people with this problem. If you would revise your answer to include a basic example of the other models and the user method to retrieve the combined set of tasks I'll revise it as the selected answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. Using `owned_tasks` and `assigned_tasks` to get all the tasks will have a performance hint. Anyway, I've updated my answer, and have included a method in `User` class to get all the associated `tasks`, it will fetch the results in one query, and no merging/combining needs to be done.

Comment: This is not an ideal solution, because you are loosing the user scope and can't combine the scopes anymore like this
`User.join(:tasks).order_by('tasks.name')`

Comment: @dre-hh Of course, this isn't an ideal solution. This is the solution according to the needs of the OP, but there is the thing that you are asking. First, it is `User.joins`, not `User.join`. Second, you can get the results equivalent of `User.joins(:tasks)` by doing `User.joins(:assigned_tasks).joins(:owned_tasks)`, but using two `joins` will give you a lot of similar results, so you can call `uniq` to find out the unique results.

Comment: @dre-hh You can also do `User.joins(:assigned_tasks, :owned_tasks)`. There are other work arounds as well like having an association of `has_many :tasks`, and then saving this association in the database whenever an onwed_task or assigned_task gets saved in the database, but that depends upon different situations.

Comment: @zx1986 If the answer helped you, you can upvote it.

Comment: this solution does not retain a true "association"

Comment: How could it when it doesn't have the foreign key?

Comment: Useful answer! This article explains it more for Rails 6: https://dev.to/luchiago/multiple-foreign-keys-for-the-same-model-in-rails-6-7ml

Answer (score 60):

Extending upon @dre-hh's answer above, which I found no longer works as expected in Rails 5. It appears Rails 5 now includes a default where clause to the effect of `WHERE tasks.user_id = ?`, which fails as there is no `user_id` column in this scenario.

I've found it is still possible to get it working with a `has_many` association, you just need to unscope this additional where clause added by Rails.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks, ->(user) {
    unscope(:where).where(owner: user).or(where(assignee: user)
  }
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Dwight, I never would have thought of this!

Comment: Can't get this to work for a `belongs_to` (where the parent has no id, so it has to be based on the multi-column PK). It just says that the relation is nil (and looking at the console, I can't see the lambda query ever being executed).

Comment: @fgblomqvist belongs_to has an option called  :primary_key, that Specify the method that returns the primary key of associated object used for the association. By default this is id. I think this could help you.

Comment: @AhmedKamal I don't see how that is useful at all?

Comment: @dwight have you ever tested this solution? I mean, everything works like a charm, however after running `expect(described_class.new).to(have_many(:tasks))` I get `Task does not have a user_id foreign key` error

Comment: @weezing I haven't tested it using shoulda, rather actual DB tests making sure I get the expected result.

Comment: That code seems to be missing a ')'

Answer (score 25):

Rails 5:

you need to unscope the default where clause
  see @Dwight answer if you still want a has_many associaiton.

Though `User.joins(:tasks)` gives me

```
ArgumentError: The association scope 'tasks' is instance dependent (the scope block takes an argument). Preloading instance dependent scopes is not supported.
```

As it is no longer possible you can use @Arslan Ali  solution as well.

Rails 4:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, ->(user){ where("tasks.owner_id = :user_id OR tasks.assignee_id = :user_id", user_id: user.id) }
end
```

Update1: 
   Regarding @JonathanSimmons comment

> Having to pass the user object into the scope on the User model seems like a backwards approach

You don't have to pass the user model to this scope. 
The current user instance is passed automatically to this lambda. 
Call it like this:

```
user = User.find(9001)
user.tasks
```

Update2:

> if possible could you expand this answer to explain what's happening? I'd like to understand it better so I can implement something similar. thanks

Calling `has_many :tasks` on ActiveRecord class will store a lambda function in some class variable and is just a fancy way to generate a `tasks` method on its object, which will call this lambda. The generated method would look similar to following pseudocode:

```
class User

  def tasks
   #define join query
   query = self.class.joins('tasks ON ...')
   #execute tasks_lambda on the query instance and pass self to the lambda
   query.instance_exec(self, self.class.tasks_lambda)
  end

end
```

Comment: so awesome, everywhere else i looked people kept trying to suggest using this outdated gem for composite keys

Comment: If possible could you expand this answer to explain what's happening? I'd like to understand it better so I can implement something similar. thanks

Comment: note: the lambda works when immediately following the `has_many` declaration, but not when following other parameters like `:inverse_of`, `:primary_key`, `:foreign_key`, etc.

Comment: although this retains the association, it causes other problems. from the docs: **Note: Joining, eager loading and preloading of these associations is not fully possible. These operations happen before instance creation and the scope will be called with a nil argument. This can lead to unexpected behavior and is deprecated.** http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Accessing+the+owner+object

Comment: Just to clarify, the lambda association is not deprecated, joining, eager loading and preloading is. One can allways keep 2 associations and rename this one to `owned_tasks` or something

Comment: This looks promising but with Rails 5 ends up still using the foreign_key with a `where` query instead of just using the lambda above

Comment: Yeah, it appears as though this no longer works in Rails 5.

Answer (score 13):

I worked out a solution for this. I'm open to any pointers on how I can make this better.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def tasks
    Task.by_person(self.id)
  end 
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base

  scope :completed, -> { where(completed: true) }   

  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "owner_id"
  belongs_to :assignee, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "assignee_id"

  def self.by_person(user_id)
    where("owner_id = :person_id OR assignee_id = :person_id", person_id: user_id)
  end 
end
```

This basically overrides the has_many association but still returns the `ActiveRecord::Relation` object I was looking for.

So now I can do something like this:

`User.first.tasks.completed` and the result is all completed task owned or assigned to the first user.

Comment: are you still using this method to solve your question? I am in the same boat and am wondering if you have learnt a new way or if this is still the best option.

Comment: Still the best option I've found.

Comment: That is likely a remnant of old attempts. Edited the answer to remove it.

Comment: Would this and dre-hh's answer below accomplish the same thing?

Comment: OddityOverseer essential the answer is yes. Though I felt his answer was semantically wrong. Having to pass the user object into the scope on the User model seems like a backwards approach. So my version allows for `User.find(1).tasks` and dre-hh's answer requires something like `User.find(1).tasks(User.find(1))`.

Comment: Agreed. I can't find a good way to do this through the association directly, so I think your method works the best for this.

Comment: > Having to pass the user object into the scope on the User model seems like a backwards approach.

You don't have to pass anything, this is a lambda and the current user instance is passed automatically to it

Comment: @dre-hh I didn't know it would just dynamically set a lambda like that. Cool! At this point all three of these answer offer a different approach to the same thing. 

I personally tend to use the scope via method definition vs the rails scope shorthand when a variable of any kind is required. That is preference though.

Answer (score 3):

Since Rails 5 you can also do that which is the ActiveRecord safer way:

```
def tasks
  Task.where(owner: self).or(Task.where(assignee: self))
end
```

Answer (score 2):

My answer to [Associations and (multiple) foreign keys in rails (3.2) : how to describe them in the model, and write up migrations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40427001/5678119) is just for you!

As for your code,here are my modifications

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks, ->(user) { unscope(where: :user_id).where("owner_id = ? OR assignee_id = ?", user.id, user.id) }, class_name: 'Task'
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "owner_id"
  belongs_to :assignee, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "assignee_id"
end
```

**Warning:**
If you are using RailsAdmin and need to create new record or edit existing record,please don't do what I've suggested.Because this hack will cause problem when you do something like this:

```
current_user.tasks.build(params)
```

The reason is that rails will try to use current_user.id to fill task.user_id,only to find that there is nothing like user_id.

So,consider my hack method as an way outside the box,but don't do that.

Comment: Not sure this answer provides anything the approved answer didn't already. Moreover, it feels like an advertisement for another question.

Comment: @JonathanSimmons Thank you. I will remove this answer if its bad to act like an ads.

Answer (score 0):

Better way is using polymorphic association:

`task.rb`

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :taskable, polymorphic: true
end
```

`assigned_task.rb`

```
class AssignedTask < Task
end
```

`owned_task.rb`

```
class OwnedTask < Task
end
```

`user.rb`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assigned_tasks, as: :taskable, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :owned_tasks,    as: :taskable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

In result, we can use it so:

```
new_user = User.create(...)
AssignedTask.create(taskable: new_user, ...)
OwnedTask.create(taskable: new_user, ...)

pp user.assigned_tasks
pp user.owned_tasks
```

Answer (score 0):

We came across a similar case where we need to have 2 foreign keys for `belongs_to`, and we fixed it as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, ->(task) { where(assignee_id: task.assignee_id) }, foreign_key: :owner_id
end
```