# Rails multiple foreign keys in the same table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys, constraints, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a model, called `Procedure` which has to be owned by a user and assigned to another user. I have a single table User,  with roles to distinguish users.

So a procedure has 2 references to the table User.

I found and implemented this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642005/rails-association-with-multiple-foreign-keys)
so in my Procedure model I have

```
belongs_to :owner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "owner_id"
belongs_to :assignee, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "assignee_id"
```

and in model User I have this

```
has_many :owned_procedures, class_name: "Procedure", foreign_key: "owner_id"
has_many :assigned_procedures, class_name: "Procedure", foreign_key: "assignee_id"
```

but I cannot understand how this physically should be implemented, I mean at table level: 
does table `procedures` need to have both the fields `owner_id and assignee_id`, or just a field `user_id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does table procedures need to have both the fields owner_id and
>   assignee_id, or just a field user_id

You should have both `owner_id` and `assignee_id` in `procedures` table instead of `user_id` so that you can call

```
@user.owned_procedures
@user.assigned_procedures
```

to get `owned_procedures` and `assigned_procedures` of a `@user` which is an instance of `User`. And to get a `owner` and `assignee` of a procedure, call

```
@procedure.owner
@procedure.assignee
```

Comment: Ok, what still makes me wondering is that in this way there is no foreign_key constraint in the database that binds the two tables, after a migration. Shall I add it manually? Or shall I delegate only Rails to keep track of the association?Thank you very much, I will accept anyway your answer later.

Comment: @sissy With the associations, Rails will take care of it. You can confirm this by  creating some procedure records in the console, map them to respected owner and assignee and call `@user.owned_procedures` or `@user.assigned_procedures`, check the SQL query that got performed.

Comment: yea I'm proceeding with it. Thank you  again :)