# Rails: belongs_to ignores scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

Table structure:

```
Bar:
  a_id
  b_id
  attr1
  attr2
  ...

Foo:
  id
  a_id
  b_id
  ...
```

Models:

```rb
class Bar < ApplicationRecord
end

class Foo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :bar, lambda { |foo|
    unscope(:where).where(
      a_id: foo.a_id,
      b_id: foo.b_id
    )
  }

  def bar_working
    Bar.find_by(
      a_id: a_id,
      b_id: b_id
    )
  end
end
```

Calling `Foo.find(1).bar` yields nil. Calling `Foo.find(1).bar_working` yields the associated object. Why is the scope not executed when I call the belongs_to association?

This works perfectly fine on a has_many association, just can't get it to work on the belongs_to.

I am running Rails 5.2.2.

Sources:

- https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to (section on Scopes)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41978449/998919

Comment: What's the SQL query when you try to get that association?

Comment: @arieljuod no SQL query is executed when I call that association (looking in the Rails debug log).

Comment: What's on `Foo.find(1).bar_id`?

Comment: @arieljuod that method won't exist since there is no column named bar_id. Foo is associated to Bar through columns x_id and y_id that together identify a unique row in Bar.

Comment: Show your real code, your code example does not reflect what you say. Also show your tables. I'm not sure `belongs_to` scopes does what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @arieljuod I updated the question according to my comments.

Comment: The second link you show is a `has_many` relationship, not a `belongs_to`. The docs on `belongs_to` association does name scopes but as a way to filter records but it does not say `bar_id` would be optional. Also, your class method and your scope doesn't even do the same thing, one would return a collection and the other only one record. Personally I wouldn't use `belongs_to` for your requirement, I don't see any benefit (you wouldn't be able to use `incudes`, `joins`, etc). You could use a `has_many` and add `limit(1)` on the scope maybe, but doesn't look like a good practice.

Comment: @arieljuod Correct about the second link, but according to the second link (like you noticed) it should work for `belongs_to` as well. Obviously it pre-sets the `bar_id` but I'd expect `unscope` to remove that. Maybe it doesn't. No SQL is executed no matter what. And yes, true that they don't do the exact same thing, but again, I would still expect the `belongs_to` to work according to what they say in the docs. So to summarize: based on what you're saying, it sounds like either their docs or their code are incorrect. So yeah, for now I'll just go with the method then (like you suggested).

Comment: I don't think the doc is wrong, it supports a scope to scope the lookup of the associated object (maybe the foreign_key is not uniq), I just don't think it works the way you want it to work. Maybe if you set `foreign_key: :a_id` then you can scope by the other column.