# Rails - How to set up a relationship where has_many through could be multiple columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I've been out of the rails dev world for a little while and am a bit rusty when it comes to setting up relationships and joins between tables, so apologies if this is a very simple question.

- I have a `Team` model which has an `id` column.
- I have a `Match` model which has `home_team_id` and `away_team_id`
  columns.
- I'd like to be able to call `@team.matches` and have any `Match`
  where either the `home_team_id` or `away_team_id` equal the
  `@team.id` show up.

I can achieve it with the following query, but it's far from ideal.

```
@matches = Match.where(home_team_id: @team.id) || Match.where(away_team_id: @team.id))
```

So what's the recommended way to set up my models and relationships to achieve the above behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

This is inspired by @Joel_Blum's answer. I think it's a bit cleaner and expands the utility through home_matches and away_matches scopes:

```ruby
 class Match < ApplicationRecord
     belongs_to :home_team, class_name: "Team"
     belongs_to :away_team, class_name: "Team"
 end

 class Team < ApplicationRecord
     has_many :home_matches, foreign_key: :home_team_id, class_name: "Match"
     has_many :away_matches, foreign_key: :away_team_id, class_name: "Match"
 
     def matches
         home_matches.or(away_matches)
     end
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done similar with the following in the model:

```
def matches
  Match.where('home_team_id = ? OR away_team_id = ?', self.id, self.id)
end
```

which at least gives you a scope.  Then in your controller:

```
@matches = @team.matches
```

I'd be interested in any other ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible model setup

```
 class Match < ApplicationRecord
     belogns_to :home_team, class_name: "Team"
     belongs_to :away_team, class_name: "Team"
 end

 class Team < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :matches,-> {
      unscope(:where).where(home_team_id: self.id).or(where(away_team_id: self.id))
    }
 end
```

And now `@team.matches` should just work. The only tricky part is getting the has_many to work [with 2 foreign keys by doing unscope(:where](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41978449/1032663))