# Rails - has_many association in run time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a Account table. which has self association using ancestry gem. Account has ancestry column using which we can get the parent account.

Account

```
has_many :connections
```

Also, I have connections table. which

```
belongs_to :account
```

Now the set up I have has a parent account

```
id: 1, name: 'Parent', ancestry: NULL
```

child account:

```
id: 2, name: 'Child', ancestry: 1
```

and a connection:

```
id: 1, name: 'child-connection', account_id: 2
```

so I am able to get all connections of as account using

```
account.connections
```

I am trying to define a runtime has_many association specific to a class like this

```
      Account.send(:has_many, :all_connections, ->(account) {Connection.where('account_id IN (?) OR account_id IN (?)', account.id, account.ancestry) }, class_name: Connection.name)
```

But doing account.all_connections always run,

```
 SELECT `connections`.* FROM `connections` WHERE `connections`.`discarded_at` IS NULL AND `connections`.`account_id` = 447549 AND (account_id IN (447549) OR account_id IN (NULL))
```

Not sure why AND `connections`.`account_id` = 447549 is getting appended.

Is there an alternate way to achieve this?

Comment: The `account_id=` is becuase of the `has_many`. You could potentially just replace this with a `scope`. e.g. `scope :all_connections, ->(account) {account.connections.or(Connection.where(account_id: account.ancestry.select(:id))}`. Please note that this will only run 1 depth though if you want the full ancestry chain you have to write something a bit more complex (recursive CTE) or use a gem that provides this functionality(e.g. `ancestry`)

Comment: Can you please show how the associations between your 2 models are defined?

Comment: Not explicit duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24642005/rails-association-with-multiple-foreign-keys, but answers there could help you understand your issue